# Increasing maxHeap arg for Findbugs in Jenkins

Tags: ant, hudson, jenkins, findbugs, jvm-arguments

I am running Findbugs with Ant with the `<findbugs>` task. I am running the Ant `build.xml` from Jenkins.

My build is stuck on low heap size : `Exception in thread "main" java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: Java heap space`.

I have [read](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/FAQ.html#q3) that I need to run Findbugs with `-maxHeap n` where `n` is the size (defaults to 256).

Since I am running Findbugs with Ant and running Ant from Jenkins, I don't really know where to pass this parameter. My options are :

1. `Java Options` in Jenkins Ant build step where I usually put parameters like `-Xmx1024m -Xms512m` etc...
2. As a `jvmargs` attribute to `<findbugs>` task in `build.xml` file.

I'm not exactly sure how to pass this parameter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`-maxHeap n` is a parameter of the findbugs command line wrapper script and can only be used there.

To set the heap size from an ant script use the `jvmargs` attribute. So your second option should work. For example:

```
<findbugs output="xml" outputFile="..." jvmargs="-Xmx256m">
   ...
</findbugs>
```